# Jquery Open and Close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to open onclick the gallery and close. I tried lots of things and search in the internet for events, but they don't work..

If someone give me a hand I would be grateful.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( '#carousel' ).elastislide( {
        minItems : 2
    });
})
</script>

<a href="#t">Open Gallery></a>
<div class="container demo-3">
    <div class="main">
        <div class="fixed-bar">
            <!-- Elastislide Carousel -->
            <ul id="carousel" class="elastislide-list">
                <li><a href="#"><img src="elastislide/small/1.jpg" alt="image01" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="elastislide/small/2.jpg" alt="image02" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="elastislide/small/3.jpg" alt="image03" /></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like you are using a jQuery plugin for the image slider.  Can you please specify the library?

Comment: jquerypp.custom.js
elastislide.js

Comment: @user2232273 - I think what SidCool meant was to provide a link to the source of where you got that plug-in as not all plugin source is immediately known - and no one will likely search for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a onClick="$('#carousel').toggle();">Open Gallery</a>
```

I'm not sure where the #t href goes, so I left it out, but adding the above onClick event will toggle the visibility of the slider.  Replace 'carousel' with a different div id if you want to toggle something else.

Comment: Try changing '#carousel' to '.fixed-bar' or '.main' or '.container'.

The problem with toggling a class, though, is you might hide more than one thing if you have multiple divs using the same class on that page.  You're best off adding an id to the div once you figure out which one you want to hide.  Then change '#carousel' to '#divIdHere'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('#carousel').toggle();
});
```

(I am assuming you're using jQuery);

**Source(s)**

[jQuery API - toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: Try again - I had made a mistake. Do you know any JavaScript?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with my code - maybe try `$('.fixed-bar').toggle();` instead?

Comment: when i click, only say error loading page...    thank you very much for your help and patient

Comment: Where does it say that? And it says it when you click on the `<a href="#t"></a>`?

Comment: it says in the middle of the page after the click

Comment: Try this now... if it hides but the background stays you should try `$('.fixed-bar').toggle();` instead